# Word or short phrase meaning "Happening on the same day as"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm wondering if there is a conventional word or short phrase meaning "happening on the same day" -- similar to "at the same time" but implying same day *without* implying that the events are simultaneous.

For the sake of example, I'll use a placeholder I came up with, **cosolar**

- "X is [cosolar] with Y"
- "I missed my final exam because it was [cosolar] with major surgery."

Is there such a word?

Comment: You could say "X coincided with Y" - or in your second example "... because it clashed with ..."

Comment: @Thruston For phrasing/word choice, both of those options are good, but I'm curious about something that *specifically* means "on the same day

Comment: Then you could resort to "isohemeral" but it's hardly an everyday word.

Comment: I think the phrase you're looking for is "happening on the same day".  Though, thinking about it, George Carlin may have a word for you.

Comment: How about 'simuldayneous'?  :)

Answer (score 1):

There is wide usage of the hyphenated variation "same-day," though it is largely associated with commercial services, as in "Same-Day Delivery." Most languages are rife with loanwords, though, and borrowing is almost always cheaper than building.

Answer (score 1):

**simultidian** - a portmanteau of simultaneous and [quotidian](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/quotidian).  (You didn't use the [real-word] tag.)

Comment: You know what? I like it.

Comment: I'm picturing a professor's blank expression, thinking where is his OED, maybe it's not so bad giving you a second chance to take that exam.

Comment: I also really like this answer because my original inspiration for the question was a name for a variable in program code; I could easily use this name for that.